# force http on one page when other pages forcet to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, url-rewriting

I use this redirection code in `.htaccess` to force all address use https :

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://Domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.Domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://Domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

I want a solution to force just one page like domain.com/example  to use http only and not forced to https .
How i can modify the redirection code ?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

To exclule a page from the https redirection, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example
RewriteRule (.*) https://Domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```